# Computing the Number of Zeroes using Rouché + Argument Principle

Tags: complex-analysis, rouches-theorem

I want to show that the function $f(z) = 1 + 2z + 7z^2 + 3z^5$ has exactly two zeroes in the unit disk counted with multiplicty.

My approach: Consider $g(z) = -7z^2-3z^5$. Then, $h(z) = f(z) + g(z) = 1 + 2z$ has the same number of zeroes as $f(z)$ in the unit disk by Rouché since $|f(z)| > |g(z)|$ on the boundary of the unit disk. Then, I can compute the number of zeroes of $h$ using the Argument principle since $h$ is holomorphic, doesn't have a pole on the boundary and is non-vanishing on the boundary of the unit disk.

Let $n$ denote the number of zeroes. Then, by the argument principle (also noticing that the number of poles of $h$ is zero), we have that
\begin{align*}
n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{h'(\phi(t)}{h(\phi(t))} \phi'(t) dt
\end{align*}
where $\phi(t) = e^{it}, t\in [0,2\pi]$ is a parametrization of the unit circle. When I evaluate this expression, however, it does not equal to 2. What am I missing? Is my approach wrong? I would greatly appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Consider $z=e^{i2\pi/3}$. Then $|g| = 10$ but $|f| = 8$ which contradicts your use of Rouche's theorem. Generally you want to use monomials for your choice of $g$ to avoid complex interactions between terms like this.

Comment: $1+2+3<7$ so separate $7z^2$ from the rest

Comment: Or even with the given decomposition $|g(z)|>|h(z)|$ on the circle so that $g$ and $f=-g+h$ have the same number of roots in the disk.

Comment: @Conrad I tried this, but when you use $7z^2$ you get 0 not 2.

Comment: What do you mean? $7z^2$ has exactly two zeroes and that is the dominant function

Comment: Ah sorry I just realized that I had a shaky understanding of how to apply Rouche